# In Typescript how do you get an element type from an array type, when the array contains different element types?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume I have an array of data that is of different types:

```
const input = ["random", 2, {a: "foo", b: "baz"}];
```

Typescript can automatically infer and extract the types, so for example:

```
type InputTypeArray = typeof input;
```

Here typescript knows that InputTypeArray is (string | number | {a: string, b: string})[];

Let's call InputType the type of the elements of the array, that is:

```
typeof InputType = string | number | {a: string, b: string};
```

Can I derive InputType from InputTypeArray?
In other words, how I would write a function that accept one of the elements of the input as parameter?

```
const input = ["random", 2, {a: "foo", b: "baz"}];

const myFunction = (element: InputType) => element;

input.map(myFunction);
```

How do I write "InputType" here ? is there a way to extract it from input?

I know I could workaround by inlining myFunction inside the map call, as typescript will again infer the correct types inside the function. But is there a way to get the type neverthless?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can extract it by pointing at an array member, so while you are using the below code to get the type of the array:

```
type A = typeof input;
```

You can use this to get the type of a single item:

```
type B = typeof input[0];
```

Comment: It was very trivial in the end :)
I was expecting for some reasons that typeof input[0] would return string, as that is the type of the first element, but obviously it wouldn't make sense at a type-level. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can also do `type B = typeof input[number]`

Answer (score 48):

You can use this format to get the member type:

```js
type InputType = typeof input[number];
```

You can read more about it (and some other cool tips) [here](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/) in Steve Holgado's blog article.

Comment: To me, this generic method seems a better solution than explicitly using an index (like `input[0]` given in another solution), since it won't fail when the array is empty.

Comment: Typescript infers a generic number anyway if you use an integer index, since we are talking about build time typings, not run time values.  Consequently both syntaxes are logically equal.  I agree that this is clearer though.

Comment: When I saw how Prettier auto-formats this, I realized it's not exactly what we think it is. We may think it's getting `[number]` from `input`, then getting the type of `input[number]`. But in reality, it's actually getting the type of `input` then getting the type of `[number]` from that parent type. Ergo: `type InputType = (typeof input)[number];`. PS: This should be the accepted solution @mastrolindus