# How to get the Type of an Array item

Tags: typescript

If I have a type for a custom array that I get from a node_module (meaning I cant change it)

```js
export type CustomArray = Array<
  {
    a: string;
    b: string;
  }
>
```

what is the proper way to define the type of one of this array`s item?

So far I figured out that that

```js
type CustomArrayItem = CustomArray[0]
```

or

```js
type CustomArrayItem = CustomArray[number]
```

works but I am unsure if this is right because I could not find anything about it in the Docs.

Comment: By specific index is more useful for [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), use number for arrays.

Comment: Is not this similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703525/in-typescript-how-do-you-get-an-element-type-from-an-array-type-when-the-array

Comment: No because in the question you shared its about an array with different element types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, both work well enough. I would use `CustomArray[number]` since that basically says 'Give me the type if I index with any number' while `CustomArray[0]` says 'Give me the type if I index with 0'. The two seem similar, but if `CustomArray` is a tuple type, results may actually be different:

```
export type CustomArray = [string, ...number[]];

type I0 = CustomArray[0] // string
type I1 = CustomArray[1] // number
type INumber = CustomArray[number] // string | number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBXAzjCBbAQSigENE4BeOAbRygEsA7AcwBo4A6LxjPAI2BRqAXWEBuAFASkKOAEkADJXTZchYmWoLhcAPS64dJs2nJUcgIzLMOfEVKJqFnfrg9+g07LkA5XgKhrVTsNR3cAlwMjFjgAHzd-QTggA)