# How do I get the type of an optional array item while in strict mode?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the type of an optional array item but I'm getting an error if strict mode is enabled. The type exists on an external library so I'm not able to change it.

This is the minimal reproducible example of the error:

```
    type ReportBody = {
         rows?: Array<{
             name: string;
             id: number;
         }>
    }
    type ReportBodyRow = ReportBody["rows"][0];
```

I get the following error below the `[0]`:

*Property '0' does not exist on type '{ name: string; id: number; }[] | undefined'.*

I already checked this question [How to get the Type of an Array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992643/how-to-get-the-type-of-an-array-item) but it doesn't work on strict mode.

Comment: You didn't give us the full error message, nor have you given the definition of `Report`. We need those to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs to demonstrate your issue for ourselves.

Comment: Thanks, I added the full error and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If `rows` is optional, it means it could not be there. At runtime `undefined[0]` would throw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype).

it extracts all types from a union excluding `null` and `undefined`.

```
    type ReportBody = {
         rows?: Array<{
             name: string;
             id: number;
         }>
    }
    type ReportBodyRow =  NonNullable<ReportBody["rows"]>[0];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=62&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AlGUD2AnMAhZATCwC8wA3gFCjkirIDuAzgPwBcwAgqqgIYQA8pF-IAHYcAtjGa0wqAJaCA5gG4yAitOzNBAVxEAjGKiUrgAXwB8ykMYvhocRCnRZc8GgRAA5ZIPeaANr44dXxhuezRMHAgAbQAiKjoYgF1TKIAGRIUgA)